# ASP.NET Build Error : The type exists in both dlls

Tags: c#, asp.net

While building my project, I got the below error message.

> The type 'tracker_ascx' exists in both
>   'AppData\Local\Temp\190\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\web_tracker.ascx.7a9a6bd4.fnv2mhdj.dll' and
>   'AppData\Local\Temp\190\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\web_tracker.ascx.7a9a6bd4.pxdl7dxj.dll'.

The application runs in `.NET Framework 4.0`

Comment: Try clean solution and rebuild all

Comment: As rdn87 already mentioned a clean helps, but somethimes I also need to manually delete all bin and obj folder of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This probably happend because you may have reference of old dlls even if u added new version. Just clean your solution and then rebuild it.

Answer (score -1):

In adition to clean and rebuild your solution, you can also delete the content of the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder in order to force a [dynamic recompilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx) of your applications.